# Animating blob movement in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview, drawing, core-graphics, core-animation

I would like to animate a circle shape as it moves 100 px to the right. It should move like a blob, in that the main circle will get a little smaller when it moves, and leave a bit of itself behind. Then as it stops moving, it will return to its original shape. Here's a crude sequence:
[image]

Is this possible without using an image sequence, or is there some way to use Core Graphics and Core Animation to do this? If it's possible without images, can you point me to what API I should use?

Comment: Do you know how the shape should be deformed?

Comment: Heh - I love Cocoa, I love Unity3D and I love bullet physics.  in this case you need to move to bullet physics  :)

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible (but potentially unadvisable) to use `UIKitDynamics` for this animation.

You could connect a circle of points with springs, and update the dynamic animator with the new locations for the leading edge of the circle. There is an article on using spring-based `UIKitDynamics` animations in `UICollectionView`s on [objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/collection-views-and-uidynamics.html), which could provide some help with this approach.

I could see this being a pretty cool application of `UIKitDynamics` if you linked the movement of the blob to a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, so the user could drag the object around and mutate the shape dynamically. It would be hard to get the feeling right with an array of images.

But I'm not aware of your requirements, so you will most likely get better performance if you use a series of `UIImages`. Or if your build target is < iOS7, you won't be able to use the `UIKitDynamics` API.